# iOS 4.2.1: Video files not being played by MPMoviePlayerController on iPod Touch

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using the MPMoviePlayerController with my App. It works fine both with the XCode simulator and the device (iPod Touch with iOS 4.3.1), but when running the App in XCode's Debug Mode on an iPod Touch running 4.2.1, I get an error which says that the video format is not being supported.

The video is an mp4-file and as far as I know the device should be able to play mp4 files.

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Where you get this error? Xcode generate error or ipod don't play your file?

Comment: @berylium: When debugging the app on the device.

Comment: MP4 is just a file format. It may contain several codecs and it seems that the one used is not compatible with your device. For details on the file and the used codec, you may use VLC or FFMPEG directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is that your video is H.264's Main Profile. This is supported by the iPod Touch 4th gen, but not the iPod touch gen 2 and gen 3 - these support only Low Complexity Baseline and Baseline profiles.

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the exact problem! You are my new personal heroine!